# How would I go about fitting a larger array into a smaller one?

Tags: java, arrays

What would be the best way to go about fitting a Large array into a smaller array? Say for example I had list1 which has 200 integers stored in it and I have another array called list2 with 20 open slots. Is there anyway I could take that large array and fit the numbers in it into the smaller array coming from both the bottom and the top of the larger array? Is it possible to have the number in position 199 be in the last position of the smaller array and the number in position 0 be in the first position of the smaller array and have for example the 9th position (or the 10th number) be in the 1st position (or the second number) of the smaller one?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Can you rephrase your required outcome?  Do you have sample code for which you tried on the described scenario?  If so, what technical difficulties did it pose?

Comment: Yes, specifically the reason I am asking this is because I'm looking to create a program which makes a graph off of dates and data from yahoo finance. However, the problem is that the user enters the dates so they in theory can have a huge amount of dates and thus a huge amount of X-Values, which I wanted to be able to size down if possible, which I'm not sure quite how I should go about doing that because the size of the array with the date values in it is variable.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the values. For example if your values have only possible values of 0 and 1, you can pack 32 such values into one integer thus only using 200/32 slots. In general case it is not possible.